# Accessing the WebOS clipboard From an Enyo Application

Tags: reflection, service, clipboard, webos, enyo

When developing a WebOS application with Enyo, is it possible to access the clipboard contents?  That is, if I copy a bit of text to the clipboard on a Touchpad or Pre device , can I programmatically grab that piece of text, or programmatically replace it?

From what I've read in the SDK documents, I assume I'd need a [Service](https://developer.palm.com/content/api/dev-guide/enyo/conceptual-services.html) to do this.  Is this correct?

If so, which service?  Are there a list of services available, and/or is there a way to reflect into the framework to see which services are available?

(New to WebOS development, so error on the side of speaking loudly and slowly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the getClipboard method on the enyo.dom.  However, when I try:

```
enyo.dom.getClipboard(enyo.bind(this, "gotClipboard"));


gotClipboard: function() {
    this.log(JSON.stringify(arguments));
}
```

I just get {"0",""}, even though I have text in the clipboard.  It makes me wonder if this isn't fully baked yet.  One argument will be the text in the clipboard when it works.

If I try the companion enyo.dom.setClipboard, I get a NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8.

Found both of these functions in here: https://developer.palm.com/content/api/reference/enyo/enyo-api-reference.html

Comment: I found that last night and poked around at the source of getClipboard and setClipboard.  Both look like they're reading and writing from a textarea that's been inserted into the dom.  Lot sof promise in enyo, but it's still pretty doughy.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not impressed with that either.  Haven't found any other methods out there though.